# Arduino hexadecimal string to unsigned long int conversion

Tags: hex, arduino

I'm trying to convert a hex decimal string value to an unsigned long int.

For example:

String s="0x4d14" --> unsigned long int B = 0x4D14

---

OK, I solved the previous problem,

I have another problem:

I read hexcodes from the serial monitor like this:

```
 char c[10];    
 char c[i]=serial.read();
 String s=c[i];
 i++;
 if (i==10)
     s="";
```

But now I can't do this:

```
   const char* string = s;
```

To use the strtoul function, so what should I do?

Whatever logic of my code, I didn't post my full code, but my problem now is `string` to `const char*` conversion.

Comment: `long int A[]={0,x,1,2,3}` cannot be right as `x` is no `int`?!

Comment: i'm reading hexadecimal values from the serial port and i want to convert it to unsigned long int.
for example unsigned long int a[i]=serial.read();
where this incoming value was supposed to be hexadecimal

Comment: @j.holetzeck i have edited my question....do you know the answer?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaea44aa48bda8261f794dcb2d1e7ab2b2

Comment: @j.holetzeck this doesn't work for hex values

Comment: Sure it does. Pass 16 as the third argument.

Comment: @PeteBecker i want to convert String s="0xffff" to unsigned long int B=0xffff in the same hexadecimal form ....not that i want B=65535

Comment: Numbers don't have hexadecimal forms. It's only when you convert a number to a text representation that you get hexadecimal, decimal, octal, or whatever. 65535 and 0xffff represent the same value, and it's the value that gets stored in an unsigned long, not the text.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
const char* string = "0x4d14";
long unsigned int b = strtoul(string, 0, 16);
```

Update:

```
char c[10];
... // read values
strtoul(c, 0, 16);
...
```

Have a look at some C language tutorial

Comment: i know it works but if print(b) i get 19732 for "0x4d14" but i actaully want to see 0x4d14 in the serial monitor

Comment: An `int` is a *number*, it is neither decimal of hex or whatever. As it seems now you want to convert a number into a string again and the representation of this number should be hex.

Comment: ok i got it....thank you....however i may update my question because i think i found another problem

Comment: You are welcome. If you have a new problem you should probably create a new question and close this one.